# Solving an IVP - separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the following IVP:

$ty(t)y'(t) + 4t^2 + y^2(t) = 0 \ \ , \ \ y(1) = \sqrt{(e^2-2)} \ \ , \ \ t>0$

I have been advised to make use of the substitution $y(t) = tv(t)$

Here are my workings so far, where $y(t)$ is written as $y$ to save time, similarly $v(t) = v$:

$tyy' + 4t^2 + y^2 = 0 \ \ , \ \ y(1)$

$t(tv)(tv)' + 4t^2 + (tv)^2 = 0$

$(t^2v)(tv' + v) + t^2(4 + v^2) = 0$

$v(tv' + v) + (4 + v^2) = 0$

$(tv' + v) + \dfrac{(4 + v^2)}{v} = 0$

$tv' + \dfrac{(4 + 2v^2)}{v} = 0$

$t \dfrac{dv}{dt} + \dfrac{(4 + 2v^2)}{v} = 0$

$\dfrac{t}{dt} + \dfrac{(4 + 2v^2)}{dv \ v} = 0$

I have obviously gone wrong somewhere, as I was hoping to get my variables separated, but my fractions are upside down

I'm not sure where I made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{t}{dt}=-\frac{4+2v^2}{dv v} ; \frac{-v dv}{4+2v^2}=\frac{dt}{t} \text{ now integrate both sides } $$

Comment: Excellent, thank you!
I'm putting it down to tiredness ;)